# giving errno 98 address already in use when deploy apps with difference google account

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have connect my python script to the google drive, and work perfectly on my device. But when I deploy on pythonanywhere with difference google account, give `errno 98 address already in use`. How can I solve this problem?

```
def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes, prefix=''):
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]

    cred = None
    working_dir = os.getcwd()
    token_dir = 'token files'
    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}{prefix}.pickle'

    ### Check if token dir exists first, if not, create the folder
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir))

    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file)):
        with open(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file), 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file), 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(f'Failed to create service instance for {API_SERVICE_NAME}')
        os.remove(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file))
        return None
```

Comment: It looks like it's not finding creds and it tries to run a local server on PythonAnywhere which will not work correctly.  Make sure that the token file path is correct and the file exists on your account.

Comment: Are you able to change the host or port from the machine you are using under "PythonAnywhere"? Try to redeploy on another instance with a different port configuration.

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz I have redeploy my script and still same. And after I looking for answer, I need to visit the URL to authorize my application. Main probem is I can't go to this url with pythonanywhere. Do you know how to to it?